# XPath expression in Log4Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xslt, log4net-configuration, xpath-2.0, web.config-transform

Changing the levelMin and levelMax value of both SmtpAppender and ADONetAppender for web.config transform file.
How to select those particular elements and change the value?

```
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="ERROR1" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="XPath(.)"/>
        <levelMax value="FATAL2" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="XPath(.)"/>
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="ERROR3" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="XPath(.)"/>
        <levelMax value="FATAL4" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="XPath(.)"/>
      </filter>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Tried `<levelMin value="ERROR" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="configuration/log4net[@name='SmtpAppender']/filter[@providerName='log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter']"/>`
and many other combinations to pickup the particular element.

How to change the values for those individual elements in web.config transform files?

Answer (score 0):

Resoled the above issue. Adding `xdt:Locator="Match(name)` helped to resolve the issue.

```
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="ERROR1" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
        <levelMax value="FATAL2" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="ERROR3" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
        <levelMax value="FATAL4" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
      </filter>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```